# Navigate2 Debugging

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, beforenavigate2

I'm attempting to create a macro through VBA to open a specified set of links in multiple tabs on IE. Currently I'm using the code below, and it works most of the time if I am trying to open 3 or less tabs. Anything more than 3, the code crashes at the "Navigate2" section. After some research, I cannot seem to find a common issue or a resolution for this. The code appears similar to below (links have been removed for obvious reasons).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub USD_ILB()
  Dim strURL As String
  Dim file_date As String
  Dim objIE As Object
  Dim arrSites(4)

  file_date = Format(Cells(1, 2), "dd.mm.yyyy")

  arrSites(0) = "URL1"
  arrSites(1) = "URL2"
  arrSites(2) = "URL3"
  arrSites(3) = "URL4"
  arrSites(4) = "URL5"
  Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  For i = 0 To 4 Step 1
     strURL = arrSites(i)
     If i = 0 Then
         objIE.Navigate strURL
     Else
         objIE.Navigate2 strURL, 2048
     End If
  Next i
  objIE.Visible = True
  Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? What is the value of 2048 for?

Comment: Yes @ChipsLetten, I get a combination of errors on the same line. They both are:

"Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Method 'Navigate2' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed"

&

"Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': 
Automation error 
Unspecified error"

Comment: Have you checked that the URL you are using is ok? Are you using Navigate2 because it is not a web address? What is the 2048 value for?

Comment: The URL's are fine. I use them on a daily basis. To answer your second question, I'm honestly unsure. Saw this particular code on a couple of sites and in theory is supposed to do exactly what I need it to do. After some quick research, it seems that Navigate2 is used to open additional tabs off of the initial tab as opposed to seperate windows. There is no explanation on the 2048 value. I've seen it on other similar codes.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a limitation on the amount of tabs that can be open from this function. Or the windows are opening too fast and it is unable to communicate with the initial tab.

Comment: Your code works fine on my (Win 10) machine which is why I wondered if you'd checked your URLs.

Comment: I'm currently using Windows 7 at work. Still have not been able to figured out the issue. @ChipsLetten

Comment: I have the same issue when I execute my script on PCs different than mine, with same Excel and IE versions.  My IE settings are not default so it could be related to the IE settings. I still didn't investigate deeply but I'm searching for a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a check whether IE is busy.

```
For i = 0 To 4 Step 1
    Do While objIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    strURL = arrSites(i)
    If i = 0 Then
        objIE.Navigate strURL
    Else
        objIE.Navigate2 strURL, 2048
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work @ChipsLetten.

It'll only do 2 or 3 at a time. I've been researching wait/busy statements, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

As regards the 2048 in `objIE.Navigate2 strURL, 2048`

Extracted from [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752094(v=vs.85).aspx), MSHTML Reference, IWebBrowser2

```
object.Navigate2(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers)

Flags [in, optional]
.. a combination of the values defined by the BrowserNavConstants enumeration

Enum BrowserNavConstants:  ...  navOpenInNewTab = 2048 ...
```

Comment: Keith, it's very unclear what you're trying to convey here.  The OP is using the "open in a new tab" flag because that's the desired behavior.  There seems to be no connection with the crashing the OP is trying to solve.  This should perhaps be a comment, not an answer.